# How to distribute work load for a report engine reading json files from amazon s3

Tags: json, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have thousands of json files in an amazon s3 bucket that are all under 1mb in size what would be the best approach in developing a reporting engine to read each one and fetch the results from files matching some user defined criteria? 
I had thought about mirroring the data in a hadoop cluster but this seems like over kill and I have the impression hadoop is not well suited for such a small amount of data?

Comment: Oh man...  that moment when you find the SO thread asking the exact same question that's in your brain, and then that moment when there's no answer.

Comment: If it helps, we are trying to use elasticsearch to make our report engine.

Comment: I'm getting great results using the mrjob python package.  Python processes json beautifully, and the mrjob package handles all the map reduce functionality.  You can test the job locally on your machine without hadoop installed, and when you're ready to deploy, a simple command line switch will run your job on Amazon EMR for you.  You can either use a shell script to get the list of all your json files, or use a shell script to concatentate them all into one json file.